# Word count program not detecting double new lines from a text file

Tags: c

Ok, just creating a basic wordcount program in C that reads from a .txt file and I'm just stuck on the actual word count function not detecting the double newlines from the file, here's the specific bit of code:

```
while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{ 
    if(c == ' ')
        count++;

    if(c == '\n')
        count++;

    if (c == '\n\n')
        count--;
}
printf("words = %d\n", count);
```

So only the first two if statements work and the third one doesn't do anything and I want that to decrement the counter as I don't want the double newline to count as a word. Does anyone know a solution? I've searched for a while but not found this specific issue.

Comment: `'\n\n'` is a multi-byte character literal, not a pair of newlines.     In any event, you need logic that only increments `count` when `n` is `'\n'` (or, more generally whitespace) AND the previous value of `c` was something else.   You also need to decide if `"CAT123dog"`  (which contains no whitespace) contains one word or two.

Comment: You'll be better off looking for alpha chars and incrementing after you stop reading alpha chars. pseudo code: if last char was an alpha char and the current char isn't add one to count. By alpha char I mean a-z and A-Z, though you could expand that to include more. The way you're approaching this would count things like `...` or `-` etc. as words too, You don't want to have to check for every non-word character.

Comment: Why do you need to special case sequences of consecutive newlines ?  They are just word separators like any sequence of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter a double new line then `\n` will be read twice triggering second `if` on each iteration since `fgetc` is supposed to read only a single char at a time. As for main problem, detection of double new line can be easily achieved by introducing an extra flag. This approach should be probably extended to deal with all kinds of word separators.

```
int was_a_new_line = 1;
while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{ 
    if(c == '\n')
    {
        if(!was_a_new_line)
        {
             was_a_new_line = 1;
             count++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        was_a_new_line = 0;
        if(c == ' ')
        {
             count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, this will run into similar problems if the user enters two two words on a line, with more than one space character between them.

Comment: Your algorithm does not make any sence. You should have a flag if there were not white space chars ( including new line).

Comment: @Peter Yes, that is why it is mentioned that this snippet is only supposed to deal with double eol and should be extended to deal with other word separators.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that is why it is mentioned that this snippet is only supposed to deal with double eol and should be extended to deal with other word separators.